# WebDriverIO Error: Unable to load spec files, relying on browser object not fully initialized

Tags: typescript, react-native, automation, appium, webdriver-io

I'm facing an issue while running WebDriverIO tests. I'm getting the following error, and I'm not sure how to resolve it:
[0-0] 2023-10-20T12:14:38.061Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.

[0-0] `browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.

[0-0] Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook.

[0-0] Spec file(s): file:///Users/aditya/Downloads/appium-boilerplate-main-2/tests/specs/android.spec.ts

[0-0] Error: Error: Cannot find module '/Users/aditya/Downloads/appium-boilerplate-main-2/file:/Users/aditya/Downloads/appium-boilerplate-main-2/tests/specs/android.spec.ts' imported from /Users/aditya/Downloads/appium-boilerplate-main-2/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js

npm install typescript ts-node --save-dev